# Undefined add_menu_page() wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write plugin with OOP approach.

```
class MySettingsPage
{
     public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', 'registration_plugin_menu' );
    }

public function registration_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Basic Registration Form', 'Basic Registration Plugin', 'manage_options', 'registration-plugin', 'my_plugin_options' );
}


public function my_plugin_options() {
        //callback function
  }
}

$settings = new MySettingsPage();
$settings->registration_plugin_menu();
$settings->my_plugin_options();
```

However, i am getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_menu_page()

Comment: just remove last 2 line of your code and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `add_menu_page` via a hook e.g. `admin_menu`. You do hook into admin_menu here:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'registration_plugin_menu' ));
```

But you *also* call registration_plugin_menu directly here, which will try to run the `add_menu_page` function immediately - before WP is ready for it:

```
$settings->registration_plugin_menu();
```

You don't need that line - it will get called automatically in the constructor.

FYI, you will need to use `$this` in your `add_action` call in the constructor because you have it in a class.

**Update**:

You will also need to use $this in add_menu_page for my_plugin_options, e.g.

```
add_menu_page( 'Basic Registration Form', 'Basic Registration Plugin', 'manage_options', 'registration-plugin', array($this, 'my_plugin_options') );
```

Comment: ok. but, the callback function my_plugin_options() is not running.

Comment: @Steve OK, but that sounds like a different issue. Did this solve the problem you asked in your question? Regarding `my_plugin_options`, you will need to use `$this` for it also - just like in add_action - because you are using a class.

Comment: @Steve I've updated my answer for using $this in my_plugin_options

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class MySettingsPage
{
    public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'registration_plugin_menu' ));
    }

public function registration_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Basic Registration Form', 'Basic Registration Plugin', 'manage_options', 'registration-plugin', array($this,'my_plugin_options') );
}


public function my_plugin_options() {
    //callback function
  }
}

$settings = new MySettingsPage();
```

[image]